# How make a hold button for recording audio for Example ? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'm new in iOS Developpment and I want to know how to make a "Hold button" like [this one](http://youtu.be/z5rlKKOQo1M) to record my audio ? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you having trouble with recording? or with holding the button down?

Comment: Hi with holding down the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 2 observers to your `UIButton`, one for `touchDown` and another for `touchUpInside`.

When your function for `touchDown` is called, you should start recording, and when your function for `touchUpInside` is called, you should stop recording.